# ConstraintLayout is not responsive

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have built a layout using ConstraintLayout for my android application. The application will be only available on mobile (no TV or Tablets). But honestly I don't how to make the layout perfectly fit the phone size.

Here's one of my activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/billabong"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Applikáció"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="65sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/inputText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.255">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/inputText"
            android:hint="E-mail cim"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="214dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputLayoutPassword"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/inputText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/inputText"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:hint="Jelszó"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:hint="Maradjak bejelentkezve"
        android:textColorHint="@color/inputText"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputLayoutPassword"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style_1"
        android:onClick="onClickButtonMain"
        android:text="Bejelentkezés"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registration_button"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style_blue"
        android:onClick="onClickButtonMain"
        android:text="Regisztráció"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_button"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/information_button"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style_2"
        android:onClick="onClickButtonMain"
        android:text="Lépések"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registration_button"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.612" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This layout looks great on Pixel but for example on Nexus S the buttons and margins like they don't actually care about how I defined them. I really would like to know what am I doing wrong. I would like to be able to build responsive layouts.

[image]

Comment: Don't ever use the *android:layout_width="300dp"* hard-coded alway try to use match or wrap content.

Comment: Also, add the image of the layout how it looks actually.

Comment: @Sunny i have attached an image of my layout! :) Thanks a lot

Comment: do not use hardcoded values for `width` and `height`

Comment: @Sajith alright, but what can i do with the marginTop between the word 'Applikáció' and the first input? The non-hardcoded width looks great (i have changed the width match_parent..and the _layout_marginStart_ and _layout_marginEnd_ to 40dp ). Now the width look responsive..but what about the spaces between each input field or button or even..textViews? :)

Comment: so the best way is get the screen height at run time and set margins accordingly at the run time it self.

Comment: @Sajith could you provide some code examples please?

Comment: You can set margins in dimens.xml files of values-hdpi, values-mdpi, values-xhdpi, etc folders. So depending upon the size of device, respective folder is selected and appropriate values is selected.

Comment: Use margins, and dont use hard coded widths, use "Match-constraint" property where you define constraint for each item, and then set its width/height to match constraint. This is always responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, you need to consider the number of different screen sizes when developing an android application.

**Different phones got different screen size**, in your layout you are using fixed size on your view (fixed size is  `android:layout_width="300dp"` for example) and the result is that what may look good on one screen (your android studio preview screen)but will not look good on another screen (your actual phone).

---

For your case, I recommend using [Chains](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb) and [Guildelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html), this will make your layout responsive.

Here is an example of the layout that you want to achieve using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Applikáció"
    android:textSize="65sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/inputText"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputLayoutPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/login_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/inputText"
        android:hint="E-mail cim"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputLayoutPassword"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/inputText"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkBox"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputLayoutEmail">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/login_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/inputText"
        android:hint="Jelszó"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:hint="Maradjak bejelentkezve"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputLayoutPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickButtonMain"
    android:text="Bejelentkezés"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/registration_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registration_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickButtonMain"
    android:text="Regisztráció"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/information_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/information_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickButtonMain"
    android:text="Lépések"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registration_button" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".9" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It will look like this (I am adding a picture from the layout editor so you can see the guidelines):

[image]

Now all that left to do is to style your views and you have your layout ready.

Comment: You just made my day! :) Thanks for the solution you provided! :)